# Where is the appropriate place to define inflector rules in CakePHP 1.3?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2, inflector

In CakePHP 1.2, custom inflector rules could be defined in a file `app/config/inflections.php`. This file was removed in CakePHP 1.3. Instead, the documentation prescribes using the `Inflector::rules` function to load custom inflections.

There's adequate documentation of how to define the custom inflections themselves, but the documentation gives no context—*where* to use `Inflector::rules`.

Should any custom inflections be defined in the `bootstrap.php` script? At the top of applicable corresponding controllers? Somewhere else?

See also:

- [Configuration: Inflections](http://book.cakephp.org/view/953/Inflections) in the documentation
- [`Inflector::rules` definition](http://api13.cakephp.org/class/inflector#method-Inflectorrules) in the API documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best place is at your bootstrap.php:

```
Inflector::rules('transliteration', array('/à|á|å|â|ã/' => 'a'));
```

Comment: Care to elaborate why `bootstrap.php` is more appropriate than the other options I suggested?

Answer (score 3):

app/config/bootstrap.php

Line 45

As of 1.3, additional rules for the inflector are added below

Says it all really.

Comment: I could change the rule that pluralizes my Payment Request Forms prf into prves, but I'm just changing the name instead :-(.  Automation is good, but not -senseless- English-centric automation